# HTML line breaker with a text block inside

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new in HTML, CSS etc. but I've been working on a little project.

I want a line "breaker" between two text containers. I've found stuff like that but it doesn't suit me. I've been looking for something like this:

```
Text 1
---[box]Instruction---
Text 2
```

I did found an example, but I just can't replicate it. I've peaked in the code, but I just dont get it.

[image: http://prntscr.com/dbcd8f]

Here is the page I got the idea from: [HTML Basics | Codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/web-beginner-en-HZA3b/0/1?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b)

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many ways to get there, this would be the start of one of them:

```css
.breaker {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid teal;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.breaker span {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid teal;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
Some text above the breaker...
<div class="breaker"><span>Breaker text</span></div>
...and some below.
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```css
.text-hr {
  position: relative;
}

.text-hr:before {
  border: 1px solid black;
  content: 'text';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<br>

<hr class="text-hr">

<br>

<div style="width: 50%">
  <hr class="text-hr">
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbWjgx